# Example: scanf and char errors

Tags: c, char, scanf

I am reading C for Dummies and am doing a example in the book. It told me to write it out line by line. Then it proceeds through the book even though the code has bugs. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

char me[20];
printf("What is your name?");
scanf("%s",&me);
printf("Darn glad to meet you. %s!\n".me);

return(0);

}
```

According to gcc:

> WHORU.C: In function ‘int main()’: WHORU.C:8:19: warning: format ‘%s’
>   expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 2 has type ‘char
>   (*)[20]’ [-Wformat] WHORU.C:9:43: error: request for member ‘me’ in
>   ‘"Darn glad to meet you. %s!\012"’, which is of non-class type ‘const
>   char [28]’

Because I am new to C, I can't really point out where I did wrong. I do know that this code requires input when it's executed. It's kinda like scanner in java.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%s",&me);
```

Should be:

```
scanf("%s",me);
```

`scanf()` receives a pointer to the variable you passed. But in C, an array decays to pointer when passed, hence no need of `&`.

Another error is, you have a `.` in the printf which should be a `,`.

```
printf("Darn glad to meet you. %s!\n".me);
```

should be:

```
printf("Darn glad to meet you. %s!\n",me);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just use `scanf("%s",me);` that should solve your problem . In C `me[]` is equivalent to `*me`.

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess that `scanf("%s",&me);` should be `scanf("%s",&me[0])` or `scanf("%s",me)` because `&me` is a pointer to an array of chars, whereas `&me[0]` is a pointer to a single char at the beginning of an array of chars.  I personally prefer the first way to do it because it seems more logical to me as in "Take the address of the first char in the array me"

Additionally, `printf("Darn glad to meet you. %s!\n".me);` should probably have a comma, not a period between the string and "me" because me is an argument to the printf function.  When you use a period, it's looking for a member on the string "Darn glad to meet you. %s!\n" called "me" which doesn't exist.  You would have the same problem in java, so I'm guessing this one is just a typo.

Comment: Using &me is fine as an array only can be passed by address, so &me and me have the same (pointer) values - if different types.

Comment: That may be so, but &me generates a warning while me and &me[0] do not because the types are correct.  Just because something compiles and works doesn't mean you should do it that way.