# C: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 2 has type 'char**'

Tags: c

I try to type simple 2D array of string take strings from user and print it

```
void in(char* n[3][2]);
void show_name ()
{
    char* n[3][2];
    in(n);
    unsigned int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            printf("%s ", &n[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    show_name();
    return 0;
}
void in(char* n[3][2])
{

   int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            scanf("%s",&n[i][j]);

    printf("\n");
}
```

it works correctly but i have warning say:

> warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 2
>   has type 'char**' [-Wformat]|

I searched for reason i found that the problem in `%s` doesn't need for address 
when i remove `&` operator there`s no warning but code doesn't run correctly

Comment: I think the warning message should be pretty obvious.

Comment: no need of char *n[3][3] in show_name(),  use void in(char **n), and call it as in(n);

Comment: There is a lot wrong here: * you do not check the size of the input, which makes buffer over flows possible * you most likely want to scan in 3 strings, but call scanf 6 times.

Comment: As for it not working properly, it'b probably because you an an array of arrays of pointer, and you never initialize the pointer so writing to them with e.g. `scanf` will lead to *undefined behavior*. And that's not the *actual* problem with that `scanf` call as it is now.

Comment: yeah you need to run the loop for three times only, as @mat69 told

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char \*’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (\*)\[20\]’](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570716/c-warning-format-s-expects-type-char-but-argument-2-has-type-char)

Comment: @mat69 i want to input 6 times but doesn't know how to do it

Comment: @Politank-Z it`s not the same

Comment: @MohamedSlama you specified that you want 3 strings which have a size of 2 each. C strings are null-terminated, that means they end with '\0', so "foo" would take 4 bytes, because it consists of the 4 characters `{'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'}`. That means every of your 3 strings could contain just 1 character + the terminating null-byte. In @WeatherVane 's answer 3 strings can be read in with a maximum size of 200 bytes each. Replace the 3s with 6 and you can read in 6 strings.

Comment: @Subinoy how to do that implement it please i try to do that but i can`t

Comment: @MohamedSlama I have shown you how to do it my answer, now edited to allow you to use any number of strings with one simple change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf and char variable problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426815/scanf-and-char-variable-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplified and corrected your program, commenting where I changed it.

**EDIT** how to make it easy to change the number of strings, now 6 as above comments

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRINGS 6

void in(char n[][200]);         // no need for * and array

void show_name ()
{
    char n[STRINGS][200] = {};  // allow some string space and init for security
    int i;
    in(n);
    for(i=0; i<STRINGS; i++)    // only need to iterate one dimension
        printf("%s\n", n[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    show_name();
    return 0;
}

void in(char n[][200])          // needs length of each row, but not number of rows
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<STRINGS; i++)    // only need to iterate one dimension
        scanf("%199s", n[i]);   // restrict the input length
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: what`s the difference now between it and 1D array ??

Comment: edit your code and remove '&' operator because it still give the same warring

Comment: It's a good point. My compiler doesn't give a warning there, I understand that to be handled properly even if it is strictly incorrect.

Comment: It's a 2D array of `char`, but each "string" is a 1D `char` array. When you iterate as strings, that's effectively 1D too. `n[i]` gets converted to `char*` by the compiler.

Comment: i really misunderstand 2d array now in c :)
when i implement it in c# , Java and python it look like the real one in mathematics  needs 2 loops one for the rows and one for the column

Comment: Well so you would here. A 2D array is declared and 2D it is. But each element is a `char` not a string. There is no C string type, it's an array of `char` terminated by a `0`, so that takes one of the dimensions.